# Python - requests_html screen scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I’m trying to log in to a pretty complex (to my beginner’s eye) website and make a reservation. Did not know a single python statement before starting the project. After many starts and stops have successfully logged in using requests_html/HTMLSession. Have overcome the security/authorization issues and arrived at target page. The page displays the server time on it and I cannot hit the proper key until the time reaches 7:00 AM. 
I am unable to access the field. I have tried the .search and .find commands, but nothing. I am hoping someone can tell me how to download the time into my program so I can test the time and wait until it reaches, or almost reaches 7:00. (I say almost because the reservation is for tee times and there is a real crunch at 7 – the whole point of this application is to automate the process and be the fastest!)

[image]

So I need to be able to load the time into my python and click a date file when the clock reaches 7:00.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what scraping tool you are using, but generaly you would access this elemen via xpath or css selector:

```
response.css(".jquery_server_clock::text").extract()
```

This example is if you are using [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would be better off using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html).

Selenium allows you to automate a browser window, so it's possible that it is not possible to interact with the site using requests, but using selenium the site you visit thinks you are using a normal browser but you can automate everything.

So what I would do if I were you:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your_url.com")

input("Navigate to the desired page, then press enter")

while not driver.find_element_by_class_name("jquery_server_clock").text[0] == "7":
    pass

driver.find_element_by_class_name("other_button").click()
```

This would wait until it is 7 AM and then click the other button immediately.

Comment: Thanks - i will try it. BUt i have had trouble getting in with selenium. In addition to the user name and password, there are several hidden fields that require a reply and i don't know how to return data into hidden fields. I admit i don't know very much, but you have to start somewhere. If you have any clues on this i'd certainly appreciate them...

Comment: If you use selenium with Firefox make sure the geckodriver version is the correct one for your firefox version. I searched for 2 days until i figured out that this was the problem ;)